# spacy- why nlp() works for single string while nlp.pipe() works fine for a list of strings?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I recently ran into a strange behavior while using spacy,
which is when I process string,

in case the string is a single string object,
I have to use nlp(string),

while I have to use nlp.pipe(a list) for a list made of strings elements.

The example is as below.

```
string='this is a string to be process by nlp'

doc =['this','is','a','string','list','to','be','processed','by','spacy']

stringprocess= list(nlp(string))

listprocess = list(nlp.pipe(doc))

listprocess

stringprocess
```

Why is this?
I assume this must be something to do with nlp.pipe() behavior which is generator.

What is the reason?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spacy does this because generators are more efficient. Since generators are consumed only once they are more memory efficient than a list.

According to their documentation instead of processing texts one-by-one and applying `nlp` pipeline it processes texts in batches.

Furthermore, you can configure batch size in `nlp.pipe` to optimize performance according to your system

> Process the texts as a stream using `nlp.pipe` and buffer them in
> batches, instead of one-by-one. This is usually much more efficient.

If your goal is to process large streams of data using `nlp.pipe` it would be much more efficient to write a streamer/generator to produce results as you need them from database/filesystem than loading everything in memory and then processing them one by one.

[spacy pipe](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines)